# Azure point-to-site VPN can't reach subnet

Tags: azure-networking, point-to-site-vpn

I have a VNet with 2 address spaces: 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24.
VPN Gateway with GatewaySubnet 10.0.0.0/28 and 10.0.1.0/24 address pool.

I am able to make a connection and reach VMs in the 10.0.0.0/24 space, but not 10.0.2.0/24 space. I have no custom routes.

The effective routes and effective security look identical on machines in both address spaces.

How can I further diagnose?

Comment: Do you have some NSG for subnet `10.0.2.0/24`?

Comment: there wansn't anything but default. issue was that I didn't update routes on my client. When VPN client gets downloaded it comes with known routes. I created the 10.0.2.0/24 address space after I created the VPN client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I created the VPN Gateway before I added the 10.0.2.0/24 address space. The VPN client I downloaded did not contain routes for 10.0.2.0/24, so traffic went over the internet instead. Once I re-downloaded the client, traffic routed through VPN. But still didn't reach target. I had to restart the VPN Gateway twice [because of redundancy?] to have it route properly inside my VNet.